# Include a file, verbatim, with a picture on every page

Tags: verbatim, fancyvrb

I want to include an arbitrary file, probably using the `fancyvrb` `VerbatimInput` command (or something similar). However, I want to put a LaTeX picture environment on every page, much in the way that `pdfpages` let's me put a picture one very page. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes, you can use eso-pic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not worth an answer (or I am missing something).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
\put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}}      
}
\begin{document}
\VerbatimInput{tikzducks.sty}
\end{document}
```

This generates a long verbatim listing with some picture on the bottom left.

Comment: Neat. I didn't know about `\AddToShipoutPictureFG` and `eso-pic.`